# Rearrange Dates r

Tags: r

I have three columns of dates.

```
test <- data.frame(a = as.Date(rep("2008-02-04", 5)),
               b = as.Date(c("2010-01-25",
                             "2012-04-13",
                             "2013-04-04",
                             "2013-09-06",
                             "2014-08-14")),
               c = as.Date(c("2010-01-29",
                             "2012-04-16",
                             NA,
                             "2013-09-19",
                             "2014-08-21"))); test
           a          b          c
1 2008-02-04 2010-01-25 2010-01-29
2 2008-02-04 2012-04-13 2012-04-16
3 2008-02-04 2013-04-04       <NA>
4 2008-02-04 2013-09-06 2013-09-19
5 2008-02-04 2014-08-14 2014-08-21
```

I would like to rearrange them in the following position. What happens is that I take row A value is replaced by the C value from previous row. And in case previous row C is NA, than value from previous row B is taken and placed into current a.

```
           a          b          c
1 2008-02-04 2010-01-25 2010-01-29
2 2010-01-29 2012-04-13 2012-04-16
3 2012-04-16 2013-04-04       <NA>
4 2013-04-04 2013-09-06 2013-09-19
5 2013-09-19 2014-08-14 2014-08-21
```

So far I've solved this with for loop:

```
n <- nrow(test)
if (n > 1) {
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    empty <- is.na(test$c[i])
    if (empty)
      test$a[i + 1] <- test$b[i]
    else
      test$a[i + 1] <- test$c[i]
  }
}
```

I want to know if there is any faster way to do this by using dplyr package. I wanted to use mutate with ifelse statement but I do not know how to select i+1 for the variable I want to change. I tryed to do the following:

```
test %>% mutate(a = if_else(is.na(lag(c, n = 1)),
                            true = lag(b, n = 1),
                            false = lag(c, n = 1),
                            missing = a))
```

But this always returns NA for first item in row a:

```
           a          b          c
1       <NA> 2010-01-25 2010-01-29
2 2010-01-29 2012-04-13 2012-04-16
3 2012-04-16 2013-04-04       <NA>
4 2013-04-04 2013-09-06 2013-09-19
5 2013-09-19 2014-08-14 2014-08-21
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `dplyr::coalesce`.  It returns the first non-NA value among its arguments component-wise:

```
test %>% mutate(a = coalesce(lag(c), lag(b), a))
```

giving:

```
           a          b          c
1 2008-02-04 2010-01-25 2010-01-29
2 2010-01-29 2012-04-13 2012-04-16
3 2012-04-16 2013-04-04       <NA>
4 2013-04-04 2013-09-06 2013-09-19
5 2013-09-19 2014-08-14 2014-08-21
```

Comment: Thanks for `coalesce` function, could you include comparison of execution times of `coalesce` vs. vector calculations i.e `conditionVal = as.Date(ifelse(!is.na(lag(test$c)),lag(test$c),lag(test$b))); test$a = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(conditionVal),test$a,conditionVal))`

Comment: @ogiz, if the solution is satisfactory you could accept it by clicking on the left hand side